# Errors using Sympy's `lambdify` with `IPython.parallel`

Tags: python, numpy, ipython, sympy, ipython-parallel

For a numerical computation I am working on, I need to define a large
Liouvillian matrix. Rather than program it in element by element, which is
tedious and error-prone, I have used Sympy to construct it algebraically, and
then use `lambdify` to make numpy matrices for use in numerical work. This works
fine for small tasks, but weird errors happen when I distribute these functions to worker engines using `IPython.parallel`.

Here, for example, I construct a dumb sympy matrix that doesn't mean anything:

```
import sympy as s
from sympy.abc import x,y
s.init_printing()

element = lambda n, m : m * x**n if (n+m) % 3 else y
L = s.Matrix([[element(n,m) for m in range(9)] for n in range(9)])
```

In the case of this example, I could have constructed a numpy matrix directly
using the same nested loop, but this isn't true of the matrix in my actual
problem. Anyway it is nice to see it written out in algebraic notation before
plugging in numbers.

I use `lambdify` to get a Numpy matrix for my numerical work:

```
numer_L = s.lambdify((x,y), L, 'numpy')
numer_L(3,4)  # gives numpy matrix for x=3, y=4
```

Say I want to do a computation involving this matrix (determinant, say)
evaluated at multiple values of `y`:

```
# in series
import numpy
s_result = list(map(lambda y: numpy.linalg.det(numer_L(3,y)), range(30)))
```

This example isn't expensive, but if it were, I would distribute the task like:

```
# set up parallel environment. 2 engines started with `ipcluster start -n 2`
from IPython.parallel import Client
rc = Client()
dview = rc[:]

# in parallel
# do imports and push our lambda function over
dview.execute('import numpy')
dview.push(dict(numer_L=numer_L))
p_result = dview.map_sync(lambda y: numpy.linalg.det(numer_L(3,y)), range(30))
```

I get the following error:

```
[0:apply]: 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)<string> in <module>()

<ipython-input-5-1f431230550c> in <lambda>(y)

/Users/tkb/.virtualenvs/sympy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc in <lambda>(x, y)

NameError: global name 'ImmutableMatrix' is not defined



[1:apply]: 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)<string> in <module>()

<ipython-input-5-1f431230550c> in <lambda>(y)

/Users/tkb/.virtualenvs/sympy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc in <lambda>(x, y)

NameError: global name 'ImmutableMatrix' is not defined
```

That didn't work because apparently the lambda function needs `ImmutableMatrix`
defined, which I hadn't ever heard of, and is not even the type of the matrix we
lambdified:

```
type(L)  # sympy.matrices.dense.MutableDenseMatrix
```

In any case, I don't want my engines running any Sympy code. The task I want to
distribute is numerical, not algebraic, and hopefully lambdify has generated
numpy code that can run on its own.

What is the proper way to generate parallelizable numpy code from sympy?

### Versions

This was done with Python 2.7.3, IPython 1.1.0, Sympy 0.7.4.1, and Numpy 1.8.0. The notebook I used to write this question is accessible on [nbviewer](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/baldwint/8446568).

Answer (score 2):

You can add things to the namespace of `lambdify` with the second argument, like

```
>>> lambdify(x, Matrix([[x, 2], [3, 4]]), [{'ImmutableMatrix': numpy.matrix}, "numpy"])(1)
matrix([[1, 2],
   [3, 4]])
```

But this should be unnecessary with the latest version of SymPy, as that mapping is already done with `"numpy"`, as you can see [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/utilities/lambdify.py#L54). Basically all `lambdify` does is create a lambda string and a namespace of name translations, and then `exec`s the string in that namespace. I suspect the issue may lie somewhere with IPython parallel, or your use of it. One suggestion, with your

```
dview.execute('import numpy')
dview.execute('from numpy import matrix as ImmutableMatrix')
dview.push(dict(numer_L=numer_L))
p_result = dview.map_sync(lambda y: numpy.linalg.det(numer_L(3,y)), range(30))
p_result
```

it may be that IPython is being too smart for you. What if you also do `from numpy import matrix as ImmutableMatrix` in your original namespace?

Sorry if this is a non-answer, but it wouldn't fit into a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!. I tried your suggestion of doing `from numpy import matrix as ImmutableMatrix` in the local namespace, but that didn't work either. Neither did pushing `ImmutableMatrix` over to the engine namespace, or importing it separately on both sides.

Comment: It seems like the lambdified function's namespace associations somehow just don't survive the pickling/unpickling magic being done in IPython's `push` function. Maybe a better approach is to execute the function in my main process in series, and push the generated matrices out to the workers as arguments. I appreciate you taking the time to think about my question!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best answer, but it is my current workaround.
I inspected the `lambdify` source code and found a `lambdastr` function that
ought to show me the code being generated:

```
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdastr
lstr = lambdastr((x,y), L, dummify=True)
```

Here is what the generated code, `lstr`, looks like:

```
'lambda x,y: (ImmutableMatrix([[y, 1, 2, y, 4, 5, y, 7, 8], [0, x, y, 3*x, 4*x, y, 6*x, 7*x, y], [0, y, 2*x**2, 3*x**2, y, 5*x**2, 6*x**2, y, 8*x**2], [y, x**3, 2*x**3, y, 4*x**3, 5*x**3, y, 7*x**3, 8*x**3], [0, x**4, y, 3*x**4, 4*x**4, y, 6*x**4, 7*x**4, y], [0, y, 2*x**5, 3*x**5, y, 5*x**5, 6*x**5, y, 8*x**5], [y, x**6, 2*x**6, y, 4*x**6, 5*x**6, y, 7*x**6, 8*x**6], [0, x**7, y, 3*x**7, 4*x**7, y, 6*x**7, 7*x**7, y], [0, y, 2*x**8, 3*x**8, y, 5*x**8, 6*x**8, y, 8*x**8]]))'
```

It looks like this ought to work if I just import `numpy.matrix` as
`ImmutableMatrix`, but no dice:

```
# in parallel
# do imports and push our lambda function over
dview.execute('import numpy')
dview.execute('from numpy import matrix as ImmutableMatrix')
dview.push(dict(numer_L=numer_L))
p_result = dview.map_sync(lambda y: numpy.linalg.det(numer_L(3,y)), range(30))
```

Fails with the same error as before.

I got it to work by pushing the generated code as a string, and doing the eval
myself:

```
# in parallel
# do imports and push our lambda function over
dview.execute('import numpy')
dview.execute('from numpy import matrix as ImmutableMatrix')
dview.push(dict(lstr=lstr))
p_result = dview.map_sync(lambda y: numpy.linalg.det(eval(lstr)(3,y)), range(30))
```

This works, and matches the result computed sequentially

```
p_result == s_result  # True
```

So, I kind of got things working, but it doesn't feel like the right way to do
it, probably due to the way `lambdify` works.